# Dagger 2 Third part Injection Android

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger

Hi im trying to figure out how to do a clean third party injection. I want to inject Otto bus properly into my services and activities.
Iv seen that you can use inject on constructor, but since I dont have any constructor with Android, i wonder how I can then inject my bus.

Iv created a module which provides a new instance of the bus. Iv also created a component which has an interface for the Bus object.

But how can I get this injected and where should I initiate my graph?

Since the objectGraph from Dagger 1 is removed, i use the Dagger_.... component and create() in the application class, but how should I inject it into whatever activity or service?

Should I create the component in every onCreate and get the bus from there? Or is it possible to @Inject like Dagger 1? Please tell me because right now it seems much more clumpy and complicated than Dagger 1 way of doing it.

```
@Component(modules = EventBusModule.class)
@Singleton
public interface EventBus {
    Bus bus();
}

@Module
public class EventBusModule {

   @Provides
   @Singleton
   public Bus provideBus() {
       return new Bus(ThreadEnforcer.ANY);
   }
}
```

All i want to be able to do is:

```
public class WearService extends WearableListenerService {
    private static final String TAG = WearService.class.getSimpleName();

    @Inject
    protected Bus bus;

   @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        bus.register(this);
        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

I look at this example(https://github.com/LiveTyping/u2020-mvp) and see that its possible, but not sure how things is hanging together.

Comment: Can you show some code of your modules, components and the class in which you want to retrieve an instance of the Bus?

Comment: This is how I want to be able to do it, it was very similar to what i did in Dagger 1, but I used the ObjectGrap create and inject to create the object graph. Now since I want to use Dagger 2, im not sure where to instansiate the Graph and how I can inject the bus in a nice way

Answer (score 3):

It is quite usual to instantiate the Dagger component in the `Application` instance. Since you probably don't have a reference to your `WearService` from your `Application` class, you'll need to make the `WearService` ask your `Application` to provide the `Bus`.

You can do this in two ways:

- By adding an `inject(WearService wearService)` method to your `EventBus` component:

  ```
  @Component(modules = EventBusModule.class)
  @Singleton
  public interface EventBus {
      Bus bus();

      void inject(WearService wearService);
  }
  ```

  You can now keep a reference to your Component in your `Application`:

  ```
  public class MyApplication extends Application {

      private EventBus mEventBusComponent;

      @Override
      public void onCreate() {
          super.onCreate();

          mEventBusComponent = Dagger_EventBus.create();
      }

      public void inject(WearService wearService) {
          mEventBusComponent.inject(wearService);
      }
  }
  ```

  From your `WearService`, ask your `Application` to inject it:

  ```
  public class WearService extends WearableListenerService {
      private static final String TAG = WearService.class.getSimpleName();

      @Inject
      protected Bus bus;

      @Override
      public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
          ((MyApplication) getApplicationContext()).inject(this);
          bus.register(this);
          return START_STICKY;
      }
  }
  ```
- By retrieving the `Bus` manually. Add a getter method for the `EventBus` component in the `Application`:

  ```
  public class MyApplication extends Application {

      private EventBus mEventBusComponent;

      @Override
      public void onCreate() {
          super.onCreate();

          mEventBusComponent = Dagger_EventBus.create();
      }

      public EventBus getEventBusComponent() {
          return mEventBusComponent;
      }
  }
  ```

  Then, in your `WearService`, call the `bus()` method:

  ```
  public class WearService extends WearableListenerService {
      private static final String TAG = WearService.class.getSimpleName();

      private Bus bus;

      @Override
      public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
          bus = ((MyApplication) getApplicationContext()).getEventBusModule().bus();
          bus.register(this);
          return START_STICKY;
      }
  }
  ```

---

For injecting the `Bus` into classes you *can* instantiate, you can use constructor injection:

```
public class MyClass() {

  private final Bus mBus;

  @Inject
  public MyClass(final Bus bus) {
    mBus = bus;
  }
}
```

Since Dagger knows how to create a `Bus` instance (because of your `@Provides` method), Dagger will now also know how to create a `MyClass` instance, no `@Provides` method necessary. For example, this will work:

```
    public class WearService extends WearableListenerService {
        private static final String TAG = WearService.class.getSimpleName();

        @Inject
        protected Bus bus;

        @Inject
        protected MyClass myClass;

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            ((MyApplication) getApplicationContext()).inject(this);
            bus.register(this);
            return START_STICKY;
        }
    }
```

The `MyClass` instance will automatically be created for you, with the same instance of `Bus` (since it is marked as `@Singleton`).

Comment: Ok I like the proposition. It means that i might understand. But what if I want to use Bus service in 9 different classes? The bus is quite important around in the app. I have it on some different services, i have it on some view activities, so things talk to eachother. Do I have to have an inject method with 9 classes, or how can I solve this properly?

Comment: Then you can use the 'default' way. The way presented is a 'workaround' since we cannot instantiate classes that extend `Activity` or `Service` ourselves. I'll add an example to the answer. Also see [the Dagger 2 site](http://google.github.io/dagger/).

Comment: Thank you for fast answeres. But I really cant see why I should go away from Dagger 1 with @Module(injects=....class) and using the objectGraph to create the connection. I feel that this over complicates things. If I could do the first way you told be with injecting the class using the bus in every onCreate, based on the injection Method from application, I would be happy. But this seems to be difficult, or can it be done with reflection?

Comment: I have watched that but that is just what it is and why Dagger 2 and not Dagger 1.  Its informative, but not so helpful for my usecase now, think il just stick with one for now, until we need to use it more.