# Dagger 2 - Injecting thirdparty libraries into Android services and activities

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger

I asked this question earlier: [Dagger 2 Third part Injection Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28871481/dagger-2-third-part-injection-android) which I got an answer to. I have learned some more after that and I believe I was not specific enough to get my problem explained. Now that question have been cluttered that is why i post this fresh new question.

Im trying to inject a third party library, Otto bus to be specific, using Dagger 2. This bus shall be injected into multiple services and activites cause I use an event driven architecture.

So as the earlier question mentions, the module, component has been made. And as the answere tells me, I have to create the graph to be able to @Inject the bus into the classes.

I have to inject each class into the components that I have, but I wonder how I can create this component injection generic. The answere suggests this:

```
@Component(modules = EventBusModule.class)
@Singleton
public interface EventBus {
    Bus bus();
    void inject(WearService wearService);
}

public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private EventBus mEventBusComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mEventBusComponent = Dagger_EventBus.create();
    }

    public void inject(WearService wearService) {
        mEventBusComponent.inject(wearService);
    }
}

public class WearService extends WearableListenerService {
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        ((MyApplication) getApplicationContext()).inject(this);
    }
}
```

Iv been trying to do this with Generics but keep getting this error:

```
Error:(13, 14) error: Type parameters must be bounded for members injection.

@Component(modules = CommunicationModule.class)
@Singleton
public interface AppComponent {
    <T> void inject(Class<T> module);
    Bus bus();
}

public <T> void inject(Class<T> module) {
    mAppComponent.inject(module);
}
```

Comment: The interface annotated with @Component basically represents the contract between you and Dagger. It's supposed to provide Dagger with the following information: Which classes need injection?  I think that's the reason why you keep getting an error while using generics. You need to name specifically the classes that need the injection.

Comment: Yeah, its only that Dagge 1 had a nice solution to it, but that used reflection which was unwanted. But iv gotten my answeres on the github page of dagger 2.

Comment: Could you link the answer you found on Github please?

Comment: https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/128 @Shargotth